# django.db.utils.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "django_content_type_pkey"

Tags: python, django, postgresql

Ran into a bit of a problem, i'm getting the above error message when i run '`python manage.py syncdb`' I'm working on a fairly old site. It' running django 1.2.6 with a postgres DB.

The run didn't have south installed and i managed to get that working. Ran `python manage.py schemamigration --initial contact_enquiries` which ran fine and asked me to migrate. I then ran `python manage.py migrate contact_enquiries` I then got the same error as above.

It doesn't complaing about any of the syntax in my models which is why i'm confused. Here are my models and hopefully that will shed some light.

```
from django.db import models

class DocumentUpload(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length="200")

    document_upload = models.FileField(upload_to="uploads/documents")


    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s" % self.name

class DocumentRequest(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length="200")

    company = models.CharField(max_length="200")

    job_title = models.CharField(max_length="200")

    email = models.EmailField(max_length="200")

    report = models.ManyToManyField(DocumentUpload)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s" % self.name
```

If you need anymore information, please let me know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Although I am not 100% certain this is the problem, there is a good chance your sequence is out of date.

Does executing this within Postgres solve the issue?

```
SELECT setval('django_content_type_id_seq', (SELECT MAX(id) FROM django_content_type));
```

Comment: Indeed, faced the same issue. Same solution can be achieved via pgAdmin: browse to the DB and schema in the left pane (make sure Sequences are visible in File -> Preferences -> Browser -> Nodes). Then select the Sequence of the relevant table: right click -> Properties. Now set the value correct in Definition -> Current value and Save it.  Probably you'll need ti increase the value. Make it 1 higher than the max PK value seen in the table.

Comment: It says column 'django_content_type_id_seq' does not exist, but the table does exist, I don't understand what column? can you help please

Comment: Perhaps you forgot the quotes @reindeer?

Answer (score 21):

This usually means that your primary key sequence has gone out of sync.       This may have been caused by a bad migration etc..
To fix this;
1. Start the dbshell
`python manage.py dbshell`
2. Find the current highest value of the primary key
`select max(id) from django_content_type;`
3. Change the primary key sequence to now start at a value higher than the value found in step 2.
So assuming the value returned in step 2 was 290780 then alter sequence to start at a number greater than 290780
`alter sequence django_content_type_id_seq restart with 295000;`

Answer (score 5):

This one means that you have out of date sequence within your database (improper previous migrations or jumps between different versions of code which leads to migrations being applied in chaotic order can cause this broken state). To quickly workaround this issue you can manually update values in your database.

```
python manage.py dbshell
```

check the current value of following table

```
SELECT last_value FROM django_migrations_id_seq;
SELECT last_value FROM django_content_type_id_seq;
```

Then update them with the command below (any sane values that are greater than ones from the output above). Usually, the first command is enough but if you are still getting errors with key value violates unique constraint "django_content_type_pkey" you need to run the second one as well (you might need to alter auth_permission_id_seq too depending on your database state)

```
ALTER SEQUENCE django_migrations_id_seq RESTART WITH {value_greater_than_last_value};
ALTER SEQUENCE django_content_type_id_seq RESTART WITH {value_greater_than_last_value};
```

Even after this, you are getting error. You use

```
SELECT last_value FROM auth_permission_id_seq;
```

Increment value by one

```
ALTER SEQUENCE auth_permission_id_seq RESTART WITH {value_greater_than_last_value};
```

Answer (score 4):

**I received this error:**

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint 
    "blahmodule_blahthing_blahstuff_id"
DETAIL:  Key (blahstuff_id)=(1) already exists.
```

**A possible solution:**

- Try migrating the `blahstuff` relation in `blahthing` from a `OneToOneField` field to a `ForeignKey`

**An explanation with what I was using:**

I was using the Django RestFramework which was wired up through a `ListCreateAPIView`, and a `ModelSerializer`. For whatever reason the `OneToOneField` attaches a `UNIQUE` to one of the join tables `blahmodule_blahthing_blahstuff_id`, ( i'm not actually sure if its a join table, this is an assumption ), but whatever magic is happening in django switching to a ForeignKey with QuerySet returns, solved my issue.

**related:**

- [What's the difference between django OneToOneField and ForeignKey?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5870537/whats-the-difference-between-django-onetoonefield-and-foreignkey)
- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/ddl-constraints.html

As far as the actual question above:

schema :

```
-- Table: public.django_content_type

-- DROP TABLE public.django_content_type;

CREATE TABLE public.django_content_type
(
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('django_content_type_id_seq'::regclass),
    app_label character varying(100) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    model character varying(100) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT django_content_type_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT django_content_type_app_label_model_76bd3d3b_uniq UNIQUE (app_label, model)

)
WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
)
TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE public.django_content_type
    OWNER to YOURUSER;
```

Example rows:

```
pk    app_label                model

1   "your_app"           "your_app_model"
2   "your_app"           "your_app_model"
3   "blah_module"        "blahthing"
4   "blah_module"        "blahstuff"
```

The hash on  `django_content_type_app_label_model_76bd3d3b_uniq` and the Primary Keys can get jumbled up if a migration fails mid process.

Answer (score 1):

From the inspiration of Wolph, here is my fix.

```
SELECT setval('django_migrations_id_seq', (SELECT MAX(id) FROM django_migrations));
```

Comment: I also found that if I did nothing other than repeatedly rerun ./manage.py migrate, it eventually worked.